# SQL query in a one line

Tags: sql, row, line

i would like to know how to replace the query so that the results are on one line, as in the attachment

My code:
select
k_surname,
k_name,
p_description,
p_date_to

from k_employees, p_functions
where k_id = p_id

thank you in advance for your help

[image: Text]

Comment: You could use a pivot, what dbms are you using?

Comment: oracle database

Comment: hi,could someone please provide the pivot formula for this case